# entitytype multiple default value

Tags: symfony, entity

i have a entitytype and i want give default value (i have the id of entity type)

```
   ->add('esame_' . $i, EntityType::class, array(
                        'label' => false,
                        'mapped' => false,
                        'class' => 'AppBundle:Nome_esame',
                        'required' => true,
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'data'=>array($id_Nome_esame1,$id_Nome_esame2) ,
                        'choice_label' => 'nome',
//                        'disabled' => 'disabled',
                        'attr' => array(
                            'placeholder' => 'Esami',
                            'class' => 'max_width esame_row select_esame',
//                        'class'=>'col-md-12 col-md-offset-0  col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3 ',
                        )
                    ))
```

My goal is give 2 or more default value to that entity

i try

```
'data'=>array($id_Nome_esame1,$id_Nome_esame2)
```

where $id_Nome_esame1, and $id_Nome_esame2 are the id value of entity type by it don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data has to be the same type as the class (AppBundle:Nome_esame)

Try something like this (you will need to bring doctrine or the entity manager into your FormType if you didn't do that yet)

```
 ->add('esame_' . $i, EntityType::class, array(
    'label' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Nome_esame',
    'required' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'data' => array($this->em->getReference("AppBundle:Nome_esame", $id_Nome_esame1), $this->em->getReference("AppBundle:Nome_esame", $id_Nome_esame2)),
    'choice_label' => 'nome',
    //                        'disabled' => 'disabled',
    'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Esami',
        'class' => 'max_width esame_row select_esame',
        //                        'class'=>'col-md-12 col-md-offset-0  col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3 ',
    )
))
```

To get the entity manager, if you use the formType as a service, inject doctrine into it, if not, just past it via __construct.

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi